# We need a glossary

Tags: discussion, arabic

We should also probably have a glossary page linked from the main site with translations for common terms used in questions and answers. For example, I assume the word "hadith" is going to be used frequently in answers.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using tag-wikis and have a separate page?

Comment: Well, a question is limited to 5 tags, and not every term used in a question or answer may merit a tag.

Comment: @Ansari Then apply the most relevant and important tags. (i.e., [tag:faq] or similar.)