# Islam.SE Glossary

Tags: discussion

As [proposed back in the day](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/we-need-a-glossary), and [inspired/plagiarized from Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/mi-yodeya-glossary)...

A glossary!

This is for Islam-related terms that come up on [the main site] (http://islam.stackexchange.com) whose meanings people may well not know.

To search this glossary for (e.g.) ``, type

> `is:answer inquestion:this`

In the search box at the top-right corner of this page and hit .

If you want the definition of a term you came across on the site, please add it without a definition, and (hopefully) someone will define it.

*To those who follow a link here:* If you see an answer that's inaccurate or misleading, or could be better, please go ahead and modify it if you have the knowledge.

Here's a general format for a simple entry:

> ** - English** (along with any common variants)
>
> Definition goes here, or a link to the term's tag wiki if there is one, possibly a link to Wikipedia or other reference.

Comment: I'll add a few myself when I get a chance. For now, if you're confused about the format an answer should take, please check the Mi Yodeya examples (and please make your answers community wiki).