# Glossary of frequently used Arabic transliterations and their English equivalent

Tags: support, arabic

Often words on this site are used in Arabic transliteration form.  This thread is intended as a lightweight glossary of frequently used words on this site, primarily for users who might not be familiar with Arabic transliterations.

A glossary was asked for [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/17163) and a kind of glossary was supplied [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1520/17163), but that's for Arabic [as far as I can tell] rather than transliterated Arabic.

I "borrowed" this simple idea from [a meta.math.SE post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/common-acronyms-used-on-main-and-meta) in the context of frequently used acronyms.

Wikipedia also has a [Glossary of Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Islam) which is more extensive, but harder to search.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to make it a Community wiki answer?

Answer (score 4):

> [Allah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allah) الله - God

**Individuals**:

> [Gabriel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel) جبريل - angel who revealed the Qur'an to Muhammad [also: Jibril]
>   [Iblis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_(Islam)) ابليس - the devil; Satan
>   [Isa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_in_Islam) عيسى - Jesus
>   [Maryam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_in_Islam) مريم - Mary, mother of Jesus
>   [Muhammad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad) محمد - prophet Muhammad [also: Mohammad]
>   [Musa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_in_Islam) موسى - Moses

**Prayer types**:

> [asr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asr_prayer) العصر - afternoon prayer
>   [dua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dua) الدعاء - supplication prayer
>   [fajr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fajr_prayer) الفجر - dawn prayer
>   [isha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isha_prayer) العِشاء - night prayer
>   jamaat الجماعة - congregational prayer
>   [jumuah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumu%27ah) الجمعة - Friday congregational prayer [also: jumma]
>   [maghrib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maghrib_prayer) المغرب - after sunset prayer
>   [salah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salah) الصلاة - obligatory prayer
>   sobh الصبح - a [synonym of dawn prayer](https://islamqa.info/en/79345)
>   [zuhr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuhr_prayer) الظهر - noon prayer [also: dhuhr]

**Prayer terminology**:

> [rakat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rakat) الركعات - prescribed movements and words during prayer
>   [ruku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruku)  الركوع - bowing during prayer
>   [sujud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujud) السجود -  prostration to Allah
>   [takbir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takbir) التكبير - the term for "Allahu akbar" (Allah is [the] greatest)

**Hadith classification**:

> [da'if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology#.E1.B8.8Ca.CA.BB.C4.ABf) ضعيف - weak hadith
>   [hasan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology#.E1.B8.A4asan) حسن - good hadith
>   [sahih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology#.E1.B9.A2a.E1.B8.A5.C4.AB.E1.B8.A5) صحيح - authentic hadith

**Quran terminology**

> [ayah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayah) الآية - verse of the Qur'an
>   [ayat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayah) الآيات - plural of ayah
>   [surah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surah) السورة - chapter of the Qur'an
>   [tafsir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir) التفسير - interpretation of the Qur'an

**General**:

> [adab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adab_%28Islam%29) الأدب - etiquette; good manners
>   [adhan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhan) - call to prayer [also: azan]
>   [akhirah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akhirah) الآخرة - afterlife
>   asma-ul-husna الأسماء الحسنى - the 99 names of Allah
>   [awrah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intimate_parts_in_Islam) العورة - intimate parts of the human body
>   [bidah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bid%E2%80%98ah) البدعة - innovation in religious matters
>   bukhari - a major hadith collection [also: Sahih al-Bukhari]
>   [din](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%ABn) - creen; religion [also: deen]
>   [eid al-adha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Adha) - festival of the sacrifice
>   [eid al-fitr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Fitr) - festival of breaking of the fast
>   [fard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fard) - obligatory [also: farz]
>   [fatwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatwa) - legal opinion
>   [fatawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatwa) - plural of fatwa
>   [fiqh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiqh) - Islamic jurisprudence
>   [ghusl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghusl) - full body washing ablution
>   [hajj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hajj) - pilgrimage to Mecca
>   [halal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halal) - permissible
>   [hadith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith) - reports on Muhammad
>   [haram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haram) - forbidden; unlawful
>   [hijab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijab) - veil worn by Muslim women
>   [iddah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iddah) - period of waiting
>   [ijma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ijma) - consensus
>   [iman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iman_(concept)) - believer's faith
>   [imam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imam) - worship leader of a mosque
>   [jannah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jannah) - paradise [also: jannat]
>   [jihad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jihad) - struggle
>   [jinn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn) - creatures made from smokeless fire [also: djinn]
>   [Kaaba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaaba) - Islam's most sacred site; cube-shape structure Muslims prayer towards
>   [kafir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kafir) - unbeliever; disbeliever
>   [qisas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qisas) - retributive justice
>   [qiyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qiyas) - deductive analogy
>   [Qur'an](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quran) - central religious text of Islam
>   [madhhab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhhab) - school of thought
>   [mahram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahram) - unmarriageable kin
>   [makruh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makruh) - discouraged; disliked
>   [malaikah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_view_of_angels) - angels
>   [masjid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosque) - mosque; Islamic place of worship
>   [mustahabb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustahabb) - recommended
>   [mut'ah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikah_mut%E2%80%98ah) - temporary marriage
>   [nafs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nafs) - ego; soul
>   [najis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Najis) - ritually unclean things
>   [niyyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niyyah) - intention
>   [Ramadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan) - ninth month of the Islamic calendar; month of fasting
>   [rasul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophets_and_messengers_in_Islam) - messenger
>   rasulullah - messenger of Allah; prophet Muhammad
>   [riba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riba) - usury; interest
>   [nabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophets_and_messengers_in_Islam) - prophet
>   [nikah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_in_Islam) - marriage
>   [sadaqah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadaqah) - voluntary charity
>   [sahaba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahabah) - companions of Muhammad
>   [sawm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasting_in_Islam) - fasting
>   [sharia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia) - Islamic religious law
>   sihr - witchcraft
>   [sunnah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunnah) - verbally transmitted record of Muhammad
>   [taharah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritual_purity_in_Islam) - purity
>   [talaq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divorce_in_Islam) - divorce
>   tasweer - picture making
>   [tawba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repentance_in_Islam) - repentance
>   [tawhid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tawhid) - oneness of Allah
>   uloom-al-hadith - hadith sciences
>   waswas - whisperings of Satan
>  
>   [wudu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wudu) - a type of ritual purification
>   [zakat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakat) - charity given at the end of Ramadan
>   [zina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zina) - unlawful sexual relations

Please add/edit this post as you see fit.

Comment: As it is your post would you agree if we added the Arabic words you are refering to too?

Comment: I wonder if it would be better to categorize these terms rather than just having a straight-up alphabetical list. e.g. keep terms related to prayer ("takbir", "salah", "rakat") separate from terms related to the hadith sciences ("sahih", "da'if"), separate from proper names ("Isa", "Maryam") etc

Comment: Feel free to edit; whatever would be most helpful.  You can add Arabic, but I'm not going to be able to help with it.